# Return Value back to controller in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

I want to send data back to my controller from service if the size of file extents how can i achieve it here is my code.

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (fileData, uploadUrl) {
   if (fileData.size > 50000000) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', fileData);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
        .success(function () {

        })
        .error(function () {

        });
    }
    else {
       return "Image size is more than 5MB";
    }
   }
  }]);
```

Comment: Use `callback` as it is asynchronous operation...

Comment: could you write the solution plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $q service for deferred execution of request  like as -

```
myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function (fileData, uploadUrl) {
   if (fileData.size > 50000000) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', fileData);
       var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          deffered.resolve(result);
        },function(error) {
           deffered.reject();
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
    else {
       return "Image size is more than 5MB";
    }
   }
  }]);
```

For more information,check below links-

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q
https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/promises